# no instance of function template for myfunc

Tags: c++

I'm writing this program but I've faced an issue, add has no instance:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if <std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true >
T add(T a,T b)
{
    return a+b;
}
template<typename T, typename...P, std::enable_if <std::is_integral<T>::value && std::is_integral<P...>::value,bool> =true>
T add(T a, P...param)
{
    return a + add(param...);
}
```

here what's I put in main:

```
int sum = add(1, 3);
    std::cout << sum << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 3):

You lost the `::type` part for `std::enable_if`. `std::enable_if <std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>` is just `std::enable_if` but doesn't yield the type `bool`.

```
template <typename T, typename std::enable_if <std::is_integral<T>::value, bool>::type = true >
//                    ^^^^^^^^                                                  ^^^^^^
T add(T a,T b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Or since C++14,

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t <std::is_integral<T>::value, bool> = true >
//                                  ^^                                                      
T add(T a,T b)
{
    return a+b;
}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PbZ9NRH7MbY5svxH)

Answer (score 1):

`std::is_integral<P...>::value` is wrong. In C++17, it should be

`(std::is_integral<T>::value && ... && std::is_integral<P>::value)`.

[Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/78b5648c87d5529f)

Another "typo" is `enable_if` usage instead of `enable_if_t`.

Work around for msvc:

```
template<typename T, typename...P>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value && (true && ... && std::is_integral<P>::value), T>
add(T a, P...param)
{
    return a + add(param...);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ZJWWmL)

Comment: @Ope: link provided, and second mistake fixed too.

Comment: ```Error C2780 'T add(T,T)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided```
I got this error

Comment: I provide working link, please provide failing code.

Comment: I use Visual c++

Comment: @Ope It might be MSVC's issue, it seems not supporting [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) (since C++17).